# How can I build a 12 by 12 grid using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, svelte

For clarity I am using svelte, I was using css grid layout before in the following manner:

```
#global_grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, calc(100vw / 12));
        grid-template-rows: repeat(12, calc(100vh / 12));
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the grid is larger than the browser innerheight as I am using 100vh. I do not know how to fix the issue I am having, a thought would be to do `window.outerheight - window.innerheight` to get the difference in pixels, and subtract that amount inside `grid-template-rows: repeat(12, calc(100vh / 12));`. I would also just be able to do the innerheight/12 I imagine.

To clarify one more time, I am using svelte and would like to breakup the page into 12 by 12 grid. Using just css leaves extra space at the bottom, my best guess is it's the extra height as a result of the browser header. I would prefer to solve using css, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: “ The problem I am having is that the grid is larger than the browser innerheight as I am using 100vh.” I don’t really understand this conclusion. Have you remembered to get rid of browser margin default settings? And how are you testing? (Real devices or browser emulation?) And have you tried setting the grid to 100vh height and using repeat(12, 1fr) instead of doing the calculation?

Comment: I removed the padding and margin from body and html, my conclusion is based on the fact that 100vh results in having to scroll the page a little bit, I have tried doing just the repeat(12, 1fr) at the very start but this does not create evenly sized cells

Comment: You might be looking for `minmax(0, 1fr)` https://svelte.dev/repl/a84d759237c04236bd058ff3d28d505c?version=3.55.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking to do?

First, make sure you set `100%` for the height and width of both the `html` and `body` elements, as they do not have a default size.

Next, set the `100vh` and `100vw` values on the container element that has your header and grid. Give it a `flex` display with `column` direction, which will set a vertical flow.

To make your grid element only take up the remaining viewport space after your header's height, give a `flex: 1` value to your grid element. Also, use `100%` in your `calc` functions, since you already set its container to cover the full viewport window and you don't want to overcount the header element. If you want borders or a gap on your grid, make sure to calculate the offset that each gap in your template will contribute.

Here is the code:

```js
const globalGrid = document.getElementById("global-grid");

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
    const node = document.createElement("div");
    node.classList.add('grid-cell');
    globalGrid.appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100v;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2em;
}

#global-grid {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, calc((100% - 12px) / 12));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, calc((100% - 12px) / 12));
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: black;
  gap: 1px;
}

.grid-cell {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div id="global-grid" />
</div>
```